# HMM Package Usage in R

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I'm trying to implement the following example of the Hidden Markov Model in R using the [HMM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HMM/HMM.pdf) package:

https://github.com/luisguiserrano/hmm/blob/master/Simple%20HMM.ipynb

Here is my R code:

```
states = c("S", "R")
symbols = c("H", "G")
startProbs = c(2/3, 1/3)
transProbs = matrix(c(0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6), 2)
emissionProbs = matrix(c(0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6), 2)
# Initialise HMM
hmm = initHMM(States = states, Symbols = symbols, startProbs = startProbs, transProbs = transProbs, emissionProbs = emissionProbs)

observations = c("H", "H", "G", "G", "G", "H")

print(exp(forward(hmm,observations)))

viterbi = viterbi(hmm,observations)
print(viterbi)
```

But, I'm getting a different result:

```
> print(exp(forward(hmm,observations)))
states         1          2          3          4           5           6
     S 0.5333333 0.38400000 0.06741333 0.01662293 0.005408085 0.008057214
     R 0.1333333 0.07466667 0.07296000 0.03435520 0.014362624 0.003879677

> print(viterbi)
"S" "S" "R" "R" "R" "S"
```

The result should be:

```
"S" "S" "S" "R" "R" "S"
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HMM` package uses a slightly different algorithm for the calculation of the most probable path of states. You can read about the implementation [here](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/valerie.monbet/doc/cours/ST/HMM.r).

For example, the forward probability for Sunny on Tuesday in the given example = max(0.533*0.8*0.8, 0.133*0.4*0.8) = 0.341

However, using the function `forward()` from our `HMM` package we obtain:
0.533*0.8*0.8 + 0.133*0.4*0.8 = 0.384.

Therefore, the sequences of states are different.